# Eliminar Espacio en select Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Buen dia tengo el siguiente problema, cuando consumo mi servio REST desde el angular el me trae los 3 tipos de documentos , pero al momento de pintarlos en el front, me muestra al principio un espacio.

Este es mi html:

```
<label for="documento">Documento de Identidad*</label>
            <select ng-model="contenido.tipoDocumento" ng-model="user.tipoDocumento" name="tipoDocumento" >
                    <option ng-repeat="option in listaTiposDoc" value="{{option.nombre}}">{{option.nombre}}</option>
                </select>
```

parte del servicio en el controlador:

```
servicioRest.getParametros().then(function (data) {
    $scope.config.parametros = data;

     //Obtenemos los tipos de documento
    $scope.config.urlService = endPoint+$scope.config.parametros.contexto;
         servicioRest.getTiposDocumento($scope.config).then(function(dataDocumentos){
            $scope.listaTiposDoc = dataDocumentos;
        });
});
```

Cuando hago un debug el me muestra lo que trae del servicio así:

[image: Cuando hago un debug el me muestra lo que trae del servicio así:]

pero el resultado es un espacio al principio que no sé como quitarlo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

**Solución Media:**

lo solucioné seteando desde el comienzo, el valor de:

```
$scope.contenido.tipoDocumento = 'CC';
```

Desde el controlador, así que carga sin espacios , vale aclarar que la solución es para cuando dicho valor está dentro de las opciones del select.

```
$scope.contenido.tipoDocumento = 'CC';

servicioRest.getParametros().then(function (data) {
    $scope.config.parametros = data;

     //Obtenemos los tipos de documento
    $scope.config.urlService = endPoint+$scope.config.parametros.contexto;
         servicioRest.getTiposDocumento($scope.config).then(function(dataDocumentos){
            $scope.listaTiposDoc = dataDocumentos;
        });
});
```

No sé si será la mejor práctica pero está funcionando OK.

Comment: Porque no utilizas ng-option, optimiza mejor el select

Answer (score 0):

intenta agregando

```
$scope.config.urlService = endPoint+$scope.config.parametros.contexto;
         servicioRest.getTiposDocumento($scope.config).then(function(dataDocumentos){
            $scope.listaTiposDoc = dataDocumentos;
            $scope.listaTiposDoc=$scope.listaTiposDoc[0].value;
        });
```

encontre un par de links donde hay ejemplos, quizas te ayuden

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361214/angularjs-remove-empty-select-option-in-angular-ng-repeat

Comment: Gracias pero lo resolví dejando inicializado el $scope.contenido.tipoDocumento = 'CC'; , desde el controller.